# How to get sum score when checked the checkboxess?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.4

I have `score` field in table of infractions. And I have many checkboxes. When I checked thed chechboxes, The total of scores are collected with ajax.

```
<div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                @foreach($infractions as $infraction)
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{ $infraction->title }}</th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="infractions[{{ $infraction->id }}]" value="0" >
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="{{ $infraction->score }}" name="infractions[{{ $infraction->id }}]" data-toggle="toggle">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="text-right"> Totlal
            <span id="total">

            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: infractions table]

Ajax

```
function scorePlus (id)
{
    // var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('num'+id).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('total').value = value;
}
```

Comment: Why are you printing a value on onclick event? there shoud be be javascript function here...
onclick="someFunction()"

Comment: This question is lacking an actual question... Are you trying to figure out why the code in `scorePlus()` isn't being executed? Have you actually called that function anywhere? Also it has been noted that your `onclick` handler isn't doing anything...

Comment: yes that my `onclick` handler isn't doing anything...